# Twitter bootstrap popover : How can I make the transition faster on popover('hide')?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

Is it possible to make the hiding on popover a bit faster ?

I was trying to tinker with the 'hide' property but no luck so far.

```
$(this).popover({
    title: node.name,
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
    hide: function() {
        $(this).animate(function() {
            //can something be done here? 
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)

```
$(this).popover({
    title: node.name,
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right',
    delay: {"hide": 200} // as per the docs. Should require the quotation marks.... Try without if not hehe....
});
```